# Minimize Debian Distro for Kiosk Application (profile unused packages)

Tags: linux, profiling, debian, embedded-linux

I have a Debian distro that boots and executes a single application for a kiosk. The file system is currently 1.5 GB, most of which is unused. Is there a method for profiling the boot process and finding which libraries are used during boot and execution? I can then uninstall packages which are not used. The majority of the weight is .so files in /usr

```
cd / 
du -hsx * | sort -rh | head -5 
1.3G    usr
190M    var
88M     lib
47M     root
7.6M    etc
```

deborphan does not show unused packages, only orphans.

`"find / -atime -20 -type -f"` is of limited use since I image multiple machines and the date given is the write time of the files to the local machine.

It seems that profiling would aid in any situation where the application is known ahead of time and space is at a premium.

Answer (score 0):

-- Not a direct answer --

Instead of trying to unclutter a full debian install, have you considered working up from a small install such as http://www.emdebian.org/ ?

It is a situation I faced when I started building Prime (http://www.prime-linux.org).

Answer (score 0):

You can find an instructable **[here](http://www.cnx-software.com/2013/07/05/12mb-minimal-image-for-raspberry-pi-using-the-yocto-project)** how to make 12MB Debian SD card image for Raspberry Pi using **[Yocto Project](https://www.yoctoproject.org)**. Step by step Yocto Project tutorial is **[here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-yocto-linux/index.html?ca=dat)**.